# Why is an explicit typing required even though the same type is inferred?

Tags: typescript, tsx

Given this code:

```
const foo = ({ bar: true });

const functionDeclaredOutsideJsx = (a: any) => foo;

const App = () => (
  <>
    <GenericElement
      // (parameter) a: string
      f={(a) => foo}
      g={(b) => {
        // Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
        b.bar;
      }}
    />

    <GenericElement
      f={(a: string) => foo}
      g={(b) => {
        b.bar;
      }}
    />

    <GenericElement
      f={functionDeclaredOutsideJsx}
      g={(b) => {
        b.bar;
      }}
    />
  </>
);


const GenericElement = <T,>(_: {
  f: (a: string) => T;
  g: (b: T) => void;
}) => (<></>)
```

The `a` argument is inferred to be a string in the first `GenericElement`, but not completly it seems as `b` is inferred to be `unknown`.

In the second `GenericElement`, `b` is correctly inferred to have a `bar` field. The *only* difference is the explicit typing of `a`.

In the third `GenericElement`, `b` is also correctly inferred to have a `bar` field. Here the function is declared outside the jsx block, but it's explicitly typed to `any`.

Why does the first `GenericElement` not work as expected, but the other two do?

Comment: It's a missing feature, described at [ms/TS#50121](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50121).  Traditionally contextual inference of callback parameters and inference of generic type arguments that have to happen at the same time in the same function argument wouldn't work at all. There was some work to improve this for non-JSX function calls in [ms/TS#48538](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538) (and in that issue explains why this happened), but it's still a missing feature for JSX. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a missing feature, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#50121](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50121).

Traditionally TypeScript has been relatively unable to perform both [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument inference and [contextual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) callback parameter type inference from the same function argument.  The basic inference algorithm would see that a function's callback parameter needed to be inferred, and end up *deferring* inference for the whole object the function is part of until after the generic type argument inference took place.  Then, by the time the generic type argument was inferred, it would be too late for the compiler to get the callback parameter type correct.  Without something like a so-called [full unification algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) for inference, as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), there will always be some limitations like this, where the inference algorithm gives up.

Typescript 4.7 [introduced](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods) an improvement whereby inference inside object and array literals can take place step-by-step instead of all at once, so that inferences from earlier properties and elements can affect inferences in later properties and elements in the same object or array.  This was implemented in [microsoft/typeScript#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538).  And indeed, this very improvement helps make a function call equivalent to your JSX version work as desired:

```
GenericElement({
    f: (a) => foo,
    g: (b) => {
        b.bar; // okay in TS4.7+, but
        // error in TS4.6- with Object is of type 'unknown'.
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, this inference algorithm was not implemented for [JSX function components](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#function-component); as described in a [comment on microsoft/TypeScript#50121](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50121#issuecomment-1203269535):

> [Lead TypeScript Architect] Anders [Hejlsberg] did some work to make context-sensitive functions in object literals behave better in inference in 4.7, but the JSX code is a separate codepath. The work here would be to "copy" that logic over into the JSX behavior.

So it's a missing feature for now.  The issue in GitHub is marked as [Help Wanted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/labels/Help%20Wanted), indicating that they'd accept PRs submitted by the community.  That means if you really want to see this happen, you could implement it yourself and there's a reasonable chance it would make it into the language!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGcsII4BeOACgG84AjFKAFxwYUAK5I4AXwCUFavSyiaGYLQAiSNABt+SACYB5UTDrA9SAFJ0AHqw4ohKGgE9prAHxxMTClVoM4AEEwMDt2NxZPdnI4WLgAHncYuJT4gHEkGiQoYDQAUS0kEEyYZJTyuAB6So4wfhRimGy3BzgGHJoAczKKuMwWTnYUCM9vCEke3rhOgfYeEbhOSam46rgABRwwbJhnAj4ofDg9CCQ6OBoIeCRrYADaYWdtgiUAa0uAdxp8ADplld4PwOFABsUkEymlSS-wSGSyOXyhWKNFKoK8s1a7WAXQWYwhoJmg3mHkWMKmPCB-BBoPBMKhlCm6Uy2VyBSKJTJfQGmCUKnUmh0REMxlM5is1nxAMJcwWSzRKQpwM5YMl5XpqXpskofgUcDhLMR7JRdniABUADTudgAfSEcr6QiGQixOJJpupsU6jp4QlNCwAbhAzBQZCT2Il4lDpJR9Qi2ciYFwephHcMSWNzT0vRxiZFSeTKVBSFUahBXihnD0JjJSEA)